# How shall i add control character to string

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

```
int stxval = 0x02; //found this value on wikipedia
string mystring = "Hello";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(mystring);
builder.Append(stxval);
```

Here in string builder `"2Hello"` is appended. how to get string in this form "Hello"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `char` instead:

```
char stx = '\u0002';
```

or

```
char stx = (char) 2;
```

Personally I prefer the first option, but it's up to you.

Anyway, then just use:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(mystring);
builder.Append(stx);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
builder.Append((char)stxval);
```

else it will just add `int.ToString()`